# Getting 503 error when setting up a site with CraftCMS nitro

Tags: mysql, nitro

I am experimenting with Nitro and getting the 503 db error when trying to connect db. I am able to connect to my GUI (Sequel Ace) but not get the browser connecting.

My db.php is as follows:

```
return [
    'driver' => getenv('DB_DRIVER'),
    'server' => getenv('DB_SERVER'),
    'user' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
    'schema' => getenv('DB_SCHEMA'),
    'tablePrefix' => getenv('DB_TABLE_PREFIX'),
    'port' => getenv('DB_PORT')
];
```

With the relevant `.env` file snippet:

```
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_HOST="mysql-5.7-3306.database.nitro" # I got this from running nitro context
DB_SERVER=127.0.0.1
DB_USER="nitro"
DB_PASSWORD="nitro"
DB_DATABASE=nitro_play
DB_SCHEMA=
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=
DB_PORT=3306
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `host` is a valid configuration key for the Connection component.

`127.0.0.1` won't work for the `server` key (within Nitro), so I'd recommend moving the value of the `DB_HOST` variable over to `DB_SERVER`, and removing the `host` key from the config object entirely!

Comment: Thank you for your help! @August Miller